# Changing uri when using get variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications

I have just started learning Codeignitor. I am developing a web application in which I am using get variable , and loading data from database and displaying it.
So my url looks like :

```
http://localhost/abc/book/?isbn=123456
```

I want my url to look like

```
http://localhost/abc/book/123456
```

I think it can be easily done with help of URI library and URI segment, but I have to strictly use **GET METHOD** only. Please suggest solution so that using GET method I get URL like above.

Below is book method of my controller :

```
public function book()
{
    $slug = $this->input->get('isbn',TRUE);
    if($slug == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('books/error2');
    }
    else
    {
        $data['book'] = $this->books_model->get_book($slug);

        if (empty($data['book'])) 
        {
            $data['isbn'] = $slug;
            $this->load->view('books/error',$data);
        }
        else
        {
        $data['title'] = $data['book']['title'];
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('books/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean to say that you should get this value: `123456` only using **get method** but your URL should not contain `query string`! Also that value should be passed just like passing a parameter???

Comment: actually I am given a problem statement which states:

"page URL should be like this http://localhost/abc/book/{{ isbn number }}

example:  http://localhost/abc/book/92384533

isbn number is a GET variable . Appropriate configuration should be made for GET var.
Take the isbn number and display all book details including book image corresponding to that isbn number."

Now I am little confused here that what exactly is GET variable here. Question posted above is based in my understanding of this problem statement.

Comment: Rite... I got your question correctly...! I am working on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only intention is not having to change the html form why don't we just write a little wrapper?

You only need a proper route for this little hack.

```
class book extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        // If the isbn GET Parameter is passed to the Request 
        if($this->input->get('isbn'))
        {
            // Load the URL helper in order to make the 
            // redirect function available
            $this->load->helper('url');

            // We redirect to our slugify method (see the route) with the 
            // value of the GET Parameter
            redirect('book/' . $this->input->get('isbn'));
        }

    }

    public function slugify($isbn)
    {
        echo "Put your stuff here but from now on work with segments";
    }

}
```

Now the route

```
$route['book/(:any)'] = "book/slugify/$1";
```

Whenever you do http://example.com/book/?isb=4783

it will route to http://example.com/book/4783

The GET Parameter is passed to our slugify method where you can work with URI segments then. The HTML Form don't needs to be touched.

If you however insist to process the GET parameter in your script, this will of course not work.

Comment: Simple and clear! I was trying achieve this using `.htaccess` but still breaking my head!

Comment: Thank you :) This would be even more efficient if you would relocate the constructors code into a hook. So you could cover all controllers at once and would not need that nasty overhead I currently have :)

Comment: It throws an error :

"Call to undefined function redirect()"
I think if user gives input let say 456 then its trying to redirect to  function "book/456" which is not available , and it throws an error. I have correctly configured routes.php as you told.

Comment: you need to load the url helper. I always autoload the url helper therefore I forgot to load it manually here :) I'll just edit my Post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but you can pass parameters to your function using URI segments using the get method:

```
public function book($slug)
{
    if($slug == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('books/error2');
    }
    else
    {
        $data['book'] = $this->books_model->get_book($slug);

        if (empty($data['book'])) 
        {
            $data['isbn'] = $slug;
            $this->load->view('books/error',$data);
        }
        else
        {
        $data['title'] = $data['book']['title'];
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('books/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

---

As covered in [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html):

If your URI contains more then two segments they will be passed to your function as parameters.

For example, lets say you have a URI like this:

```
example.com/index.php/products/shoes/sandals/123
```

Your function will be passed URI segments 3 and 4 ("sandals" and "123"):

```
<?php
class Products extends CI_Controller {

    public function shoes($sandals, $id)
    {
        echo $sandals;
        echo $id;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I am little confused, like I have a form in which user enter a get variable "isbn" , which is then redirected to method book of this controller and then rest of the part. If I will use method suggested by you then how will I be able to get value of "isbn" i.e get variable which is submitted through form.

Comment: I get what you are saying. It looks like @Thomas David Plat's answer does what you are looking for.